# Magento2 addAttributeToFilter not working with Multi Select Attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, multiselect-attribute

I am try to filter Product collection attribute Multi Select with Following code but it not working with IN or FINESET.

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory 

$collection1 = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$collection1->setStore(1);
$collection1->addAttributeToFilter('industry', array('in' => array(7)));
```

Suppose Product attribute "industry" contain 8,7,2 In this case above filter not working.

anyone have idea about this.

Answer (score 1):

It working fine with following syntax.

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute,
    array(
        array('finset'=> array('237')),
        array('finset'=> array('238')),
        array('finset'=> array('239')),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection1 = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$collection1->setStore(1);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('industry', ['in' => [2, 7, 8]]);
```

Comment: I have check with above syntax but getting same result.

Comment: @NiranjanGondaliya code edited

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 $collection1->setStore(1);
```

to

```
 $collection1->setStore(0);
```

Comment: I have check but getting same result.